# How to use my same todo list online from every device

Tags: javascript

Im learning JS and i builded a simple shopping list (works same like a todo list)

For the first, the list works fine for me, but now i want to upload these on a rented server and want to use the same content from differrent diveses, like writing the list on PC and using or editing it on cell phone. (Login in and stuff, comes later :) )

```
[Here is my Code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Craddus/5t2w7fp8/4/)
```

Now i know, that JavaScript doesnt really change documents, so whats todo that these list (items) save online permanent. Can i also do this with JavaScript?

Whats the next steps? Im a complete greenhorn in programming and i dont find a beginning for these solution.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: _"Here is my Code on JSFiddle"_ - please go read [ask] and [mre]. The relevant code to understand/reproduce your problem, belongs directly into your question, and not just dumped onto some 3rd-party platform.

Comment: You need server for store data. Google `todo list with node js and database`

Comment: _"Can i also do this with JavaScript?"_ - not with _client-side_ JavaScript alone. You could use server-side JavaScript (node), or any other server-side language, that is able to receive the data you send it from the client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To save list (items) online permanent you have to use `php` and save everything in `database` using `sql`.